# Npm Won't Create Build Directory Even from Sudo

Tags: node.js, npm, sudo, webpack, cp

Hullo all,

I get the below error message when running my `npm run` command for my app:

`cp: cannot create regular file ‘./build/index.html’: No such file or directory
http://localhost:8080/
webpack result is served from /
content is served from ./build/
Hash: 742d890d44a97a9ab393
Version: webpack 1.12.2`

The dev script is:

`cp ./src/index.html ./build/index.html & webpack-dev-server --hot`

I first suspected this was a permissions error, so I ran npm as sudo, but that got no cigar.  Then I made the files myself one by one until there were no more error messages.  Lo and behold that worked!  What should I do to explore this problem further?

I'm using node 4.0.0 and npm 2.14.3.

Comment: dunno if this will help, but i ran into this earlier today (with install tho, not run) : [fixing-npm-permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the error messages indicate the problem was that the `build` directory did not exist. (Is that one of the things you had to create manually to get it to work?) One solution would be to change the script to do `mkdir -p ./build` before doing the `cp ./source/index.html ./build/index.html`.

Comment: that does fix the problem so long as the command is run from sudo. I'm not sure I like that the user has to add this command to their script, though